# jQuery UI combobox: _renderItem breaks Show all button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete, renderer

I've got **jQuery UI autocomplete combobox** working (basically a copy of an example on http://jqueryui.com) but I cannot owerwrite item rendering with `_renderItem` method without breaking the *Show All* button in my combobox.

Versions:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/H3rGB/3/ - working without custom `_renderItem`
2. http://jsfiddle.net/H3rGB/5/ - *Show All* button **not working**. `_renderItem` works even though it's HTML output looks the same (for testing purpouses, of course I want a different output in the end).

So the 2 versions differ in just this:

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {                        
    return $("<li></li>")
    .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
    .append("changed: " + item.label)
    .appendTo(ul);
}
```

I'm using both jQuery and jQuery UI 1.10.

I've been stuck here for hours so I rather ask somebody more experienced here than me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to make a solution.

The core problem was this: when I called `this.input.autocomplete("instance")`, the object `this.input` was changed. It became an anonymous function instead of jQuery object.

So I came up with this workaround:

```
// normal initialization as in jQuery demo example
this.input = $("<input>")
    ...;

// save the input object for later    
var input2 = this.input;

// ovewrrite renderItem with my function
this.input.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    item.label = item.label.replace(/(.*\>)/i, '<span style="color: #aaa;">$1</span>');
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("ui-autocomplete", item)
        .append(item.label)
        .appendTo(ul);
};

// restore "broken" input object
this.input = input2;
```